# Viewing Coursera WRAC files

Tags: archiving

I'm trying to download and view the coursera archive here.
https://archive.org/details/archiveteam_coursera
The archive is in WARC files. What's the best way to view them? When I use WARC player the links don't work.

Comment: You can't use WinRAR? Or is my understanding of your question wrong?

Answer (score 0):

#### When I use WARC player the links don't work.

They are `.gz` files. You need to download them and `gunzip` them.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the .gz opens. However, the file is not viewable with WARC player. I want to find a way to extract the files so I could view them one-by-one